# VBA copy and past loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write a macro that goes into an infinite amount of sheets and copies and pastes a data range from A10:E10, A11:E11 and so on until it hits a blank cell until pastes it into a new tab until it has gone through each sheet and grabbed the data. I have tried to use the code below, but it will only let me paste one cell and if I change the range to more than one it pastes over and leaves out data. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set DestSh = wb.Sheets("Combined")

' Loop through worksheets that start with the name "20"
i = 4
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name = "Data" Then Exit Sub
    sh.Range("E10").Copy

  With DestSh.Range("AF" & i)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



    End With
i = i + 1

Next
```

Comment: I'm sure you didn't actually mean "an infinite number of sheets." :-)

Comment: Add a last row calculation (`lr`) inside your loop to tell you where to paste

Comment: I wonder, why the code is `sh.Range("E10").Copy` if actually what you want to copy is cell A10:E11. To avoid it replace the already pasted data, I think u have to put `i=i+2` because the copied cells are in two rows.

Comment: @BigBen - of course the OP did. It's the never ending workbook!